# How to replace any NAs in dataframe with the previous value in the same row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, na

I have a data frame that contains several scattered NA values. I would like to fill those NAs with the values immediately preceding it in the cell to the left (same row) or the following cell to the right (same row) if a value doesn't exist to the left or is NA. It seems like using `zoo::na.locf` or `tidyr::fill()` can help with this but it only seems to work by taking the previous/next value either above or below in the same column.

I currently have this code but it's only filling based on above values in same column:

```
lapply(df, function(x) zoo::na.locf(zoo::na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast = TRUE))
```

My dataframe **df** looks like this:

```
  C1 C2 C3 C4
1  2  1  9  2
2 NA  5  1  1
3  1 NA  3  8
4  3 NA NA  4

structure(list(C1 = c(2, NA, 1, 3), C2 = c(1, 5, NA, NA), C3 = c(9, 
1, 3, NA), C4 = c(2, 1, 8, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

After filling the NA values, I would like it to look like this:

```
  C1 C2 C3 C4
1  2  1  9  2
2  5  5  1  1
3  1  1  3  8
4  3  3  3  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`na.locf` can directly work on dataframes but it works column-wise. If you want to make it run row-wise you can transpose the dataframe. You can also use `fromLast = TRUE` to fill the data from opposite direction. Finally, we use `coalesce` to select the first non-NA value from the two vectors.

```
library(zoo)

df[] <- dplyr::coalesce(c(t(na.locf(t(df), na.rm = FALSE))), 
                        c(t(na.locf(t(df), na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE))))
df

#  C1 C2 C3 C4
#1  2  1  9  2
#2  5  5  1  1
#3  1  1  3  8
#4  3  3  3  4
```

Comment: Only thing I needed to do was wrap the coalesced vectors in a matrix ```matrix(coalesce...))``` to get them back into matrix form and it worked! Otherwise I was getting a compatibility error between existing and assigned data.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed not the usual way to store data, but if you just transpose you can use `tidyr::fill()`. Only downside is that it adds quite a bit of wrapping code.

```
xx <- structure(list(C1 = c(2, NA, 1, 3), C2 = c(1, 5, NA, NA), C3 = c(9, 
                                                                 1, 3, NA), C4 = c(2, 1, 8, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")


xx %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  tidyr::fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  set_names(names(xx))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#     C1    C2    C3    C4
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     2     1     9     2
#2     5     5     1     1
#3     1     1     3     8
#4     3     3     3     4
```

Answer (score 2):

With `apply` and `na.locf`

```
library(zoo)
df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) na.locf0(na.locf0(x), fromLast = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
df
#   C1 C2 C3 C4
#1  2  1  9  2
#2  5  5  1  1
#3  1  1  3  8
#4  3  3  3  4
```

Comment: This seems to work. What exactly is ```na.locf0()``` doing differently than ```na.locf()```? Can't seem to find documentation on it

Comment: @fastlanes It doesn't have `na.rm = TRUE` argument as in `na.locf` so, if the NAs are the beginning, `na.locf` removes those observations automatically while `na.locf0` keeps it. i.e. `v1 <- c(NA, NA, 2, NA, 3); na.locf(v1)#[1] 2 2 3` and `na.locf0(v1)#
[1] NA NA  2  2  3` i.e. the `na.locf` can create issues with the length when there are NAs at the beginning or at end (if `fromLast = TRUE` is used)`